# user specific menu tab

Tags: 7, users, routes

I have a menu tab on nodes which is visible to everyone on the site. But I want it to be user specific. If the logged in user is the one who created that node, only he should be able to see the menu tab. Is it possible to do this using views ?

Comment: [Menu per role](http://www.drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) module can do that for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Views, you can add tabs and set argument (aka contextual filter) validators.

user will not see the tab if the argument is invalid.

See [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16132/drupal-7-views-filter-by-owner/16133#16133) post. You will need to set arguments as described in [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41894/how-do-prevent-other-users-from-seeing-certain-views-in-a-user-profile/41899#41899) post.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add access argument "edit own page content" replace page with you content-type name. If you want more complex permissions you can add your own access callback to a menu item which will return true or false. For further information check http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

Comment: I created the menu tab using views not programmatically. So can i do this using views ?

Comment: You can also this in views under page settings->menu->select menu tab->fill out the details and choose Navigation menu. After saving view clear cache.

Comment: I created the menu tab, the issue it setting the access permissions! under the permissions i don't see 'edit own page content'

Comment: In access permission settings under node option group `Basic Page: Edit own content`.

Comment: Can i do something where I can set it for all the content types and not just basic page ?

Comment: There is only one way to do it [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7). You have to add your own access callback to a menu item which will return true or false.