# Views for specific user profiles

Tags: views

I have  view that displays a users nodes. When you view "my account" it displays all the nodes you created in a view.  However when viewing another user's profile, you don't see the node's that they added, instead you still see your nodes.  Is this something I would need to set up with views and rules?

tl;dr How can I create a view that displays user specific content on their own profiles.

X user's content on X user's profile
Y user's content on Y user's profle

EDIT
Answer:
[Drupal 7 views, filter by owner](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16132/drupal-7-views-filter-by-owner)

Answer (score 1):

To list content owned by a user you can:

1. Create a View that lists content
2. Create a Page Display within that view
3. Configure a "Contextual filter" for "Content: Author UID" and set its "When the filter value is NOT in the URL" setting to "Provide a default value", then select "User ID from URL" for the "Type".

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to limit a certain user, you can select the filter criteria of User: Name, or User: The User ID, whatever suits you.