# Views to use currentlylogged in UID or override via URL

Tags: views

I have followed this:

[Drupal 7 views, filter by owner](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16132/drupal-7-views-filter-by-owner)

I have a situation where I want the view to show only results by author UID of currently logged in user and/or have the URI explicitly provide the UID.

I can get one or the other to work but not both -- the URI scheme I have is:

http://mydomain.local/myproject/%/test/test.html

I was thinking the placement of the % might affect the results -- it does not.

Ideally when someone access the page:

http://mydomain.local/myproject/test/

And they are logged in the see the results specific to them

When someone accesses the page:

http://mydomain.local/myproject/3/test

The see only the results for the specific user UID = 3

Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're going to need to do is clone your display. One display using path 'myproject/test' where you contextual filter uses 'Provide default value' when the filter is not in the URL, with 'User ID from the logged in user' as the type.

The other display will use the path 'myproject/%/test' and since the filter in this case IS provided by the URL, you can do something like 'Show "Page not Found"' if the filter value is not provided by the URL. You'll probably also want to specify a validation criteria using the numeric validator with 'Show "Page not found"' as the action to take if it doesn't validate.

Comment: This is what I was thinking -- thank you both for the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.

You need views php for this https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php

1) On your page view add a block.

2) click on your contextual filter and scroll all the way down. You will see a blue "**MORE**" button. Click on it and scroll all the way down again. You will see a check box that says, "**Allow multiple values**" check mark it and **click APPLY**.

3) **If you want to test it**, put your contextual filter on "Provide default value" then "fix value" and type two user uid with a + in between them. Ex: 1+2. After seeing that it works, put it back on **Display all results for the specified field**.

4) Now **go back to your page view**. Add user uid as field. It should show the user uid based on the % value, exclude this field from display.

5) Add a new field, Global: PHP.

Leave value code empty and **under output code type**

> NOTE: We are going to use the global user variable to get the current
>   logged in user info.  We are also going to use print views_embed_view('my_view', 'block_1', $arg1, $arg2); to render the view.

```
<?php 
global $user;
print views_embed_view('my_view', 'block_1', $user->uid+$row->uid);
?>
```

> NOTES:
>
> make sure the block_1 matches the machine name, which is found under
>   **OTHER** of your block view.
>
> $user->uid is from the logged in user and $row->uid is the uid of the
>   % which we excluded

If you are not able to follow this let me know and I can provide you with an export view example.